# Cassandra for changing information need

Tags: database-design, cassandra, data-modeling, datastax, denormalization

When I read about Cassandra and Data Modeling, it says that Cassandra has a query based data modeling. So what I understood from this is, in a database I need to have a separate CF for every select query I want to execute. Is this true?
Is it fine to use Cassandra to create a database where information need is not clearly defined (i.e. new queries can be introduced in the future) ?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes, the long answer is, it depends on your use case.

Cassandra best practices are designed to help users achieve sub millisecond latencies and very high transaction volumes (millions / second). In order to achieve these results, you need to be very deliberate about your data model.

That being said, if your workload and SLA's are a bit more flexible than what I described, you will have some wiggle room. Some of the datastax enterprise integrations like search and analytics will also give you flexibility for ad-hoc querying.

It is likely that you can design tables that will support more than one query. However, don't be afraid of data duplication, it is often a good trade-off for performance and a c* best practice.

You can also modify existing tables using ALTER TABLE syntax:
http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/cql/cql_reference/alter_table_r.html

Comment: I'm working on developing a language corpus. So what if there is chance of some different queries may introduced in future? Can Cassandra provide those functionalities? Will I have to create new tables for those?

Comment: Not sure I follow your question. If you have new queries in your application, 1) you can see if your existing tables can support the new query or alter them appropriately if this can be done without breaking existing functionality 2) you can try to address them using DSE search or analytics if you're on DSE. http://www.datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/4.0/datastax_enterprise/srch/srchIntro.html